# MySQL query using Update, Set, Sum, Where, and Group By

Tags: mysql

I have a table below named deposit

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 500 | 3 |

When I update the table with the query below I get the following table, which is not what I want

```
UPDATE deposit SET deposit_amount = (SELECT SUM(deposit_amount) - 50) WHERE comp_id =1
```

What the query above does is to subtract 50 from each of the corresponding comp_id

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 509 | 3 |

But the table below is what I need.
Because seeing the first table and with the query I provided where comp_id =1, we have 100 + 100 = 200, and then 200 - 50 = 150. So because comp_id has 1 IDs two times, therefore we have 75 and 75 because 75 +75 is 150. So we have the table below, which is what I need.

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 1 |
| 2 | 75 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 500 | 3 |

Please how do I write the query to suit the table I need? Help!

Comment: Is the amount supposed to be evenly split amongst the deposits that share a comp_id? Even if they weren't before?

Comment: Where did the 50 come from?  Does the 50 not apply to comp_ids 2 and 3?

Comment: @dwhitemv yes the amount got to be split evenly on the corresponding comp_id

Comment: @RickJames the 50 only applies to the corresponding comp_id, in this case is 1 according to the query. If comp_id is 2 then amounts that fall under 2 (comp_id) would be affected

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

```
UPDATE deposit AS d1
    JOIN ( SELECT 100 / COUNT(*) AS each FROM deposit As d2
               WHERE d2.comp_id = d1.comp_id 
         ) AS x
    SET d1.deposit_amount = d1.deposit_amount - x.each
    WHERE d1.comp_id = 1;
```

If there are 3 rows instead of 2, then 100/3 = 33.33333... -- This will lead to a roundoff error somewhere.  What do you plan to do with the extra or lost cent?  I will *not* be easy to write SQL to give the rows 33,33,34.  For this, I recommend application code, not SQL.